# Is this explanation of ternary operator valid?

Tags: c++, operators, conditional-statements

**Question:**

- I want to know if this explanation of the ternary operator is valid.

> var = (condition) ? set value if condition one : set value of condition two;

If the condition is something than the value of the variable will be something. If it's not the value will be different. Basically assign a variable with a value based on a condition. Is this explanation valid? I need to know this if I'm understanding this correctly.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

bool maxEntries()
{
    int entries = 11;
    bool users = (entries > 10) ? true : false;
    return users;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    if(maxEntries())
    {
        std::cout << "Entries are greater than 10." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Entries are less than 10." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
} 

.
```

Comment: I'd say "*return value if condition....*" or "*result of ternary expression if condition...*" instead of "set," but that sounds right...when you plugged in values and tested it, did you find that your explanation was correct?

Comment: Another way to say `bool users = (entries > 10) ? true : false;` is `bool users = entries > 10;`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if this explanation of the ternary operator is valid.

That explanation is not for ternary operator, but for expression that assigns to a variable result of ternary operator. Ternary operator itself is more than that:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;

condition ? a = 1 : b = 2; // based on condition assign 1 to a or 2 to b
( condition ? a : b ) = 100; // based on condition assign 100 to a or b
```

in your case

```
condition ? value1 : value2; // result of ternary operator either value1 or value2 based on condition
```

you then use the result to assign to a variable, so your explanation is not for ternary operator but for whole expression that uses ternary:

```
var = condition ? value1 : value2;
```

you may think this is neat picking but if somebody would read your explanation he may think that assignment to a variable is part of the ternary operator itself, but that is not the case. For example:

```
 function_call( condition ? value_on_true : value_on_false );
```

Also this at least confusing: "If the condition is something" it should be "if the condition is `true` then first otherwise (condition is `false`) the second.